# How can I add class or inline-style to a component's prop in React?

Tags: reactjs

I'm quite new to React and coding. How do I add a class or style to item.specTitle in this here code?

```
const spec1 = [
  {specTitle: "Size", specDescription: "Large suitcase."},
  {specTitle: "Color", specDescription: "Red car."},
  {specTitle: "Other", specDescription: "Other here."},
];
...

<List
  dataSource={spec1}
  renderItem={item => (
    <List.Item>
      <List.Item.Meta
         description={item.specTitle + item.specDescription}
      />
    </List.Item>
  )}
 />
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Could you edit your question to include the code for the `List.Item.Meta` component? It's hard to answer it otherwise.

The `item.specTitle` is just a string so you cannot add styling to that. You have two options:

1. In the `List.Item.Meta` component you can add a className or inline
   style where the `specTitle` prop is rendered.
2. Change the `List.Item.Meta` component `specTitle` prop so that it can be a React node instead of a string and then you can change your spec1 to something like:

```js
const spec1 = [
  { specTitle: <h1 className="specTitle">Size</h1>, ...},
  { specTitle: <h1 className="specTitle">Color</h1>, ...}
]
```